# Can I pass variable to select statement as column name with where condition value from variable

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following simple select statement:

```
DECLARE @value varchar(10) 
SET @value = 'intStep' 

SELECT @value FROM dbo.tblBatchDetail
```

I have tried

```
 SELECT CAST(@value AS varchar(10)) FROM dbo.tblBatchDetail
```

and all I get a list of intstep

QUESTION: can I pass variable as column name to this statement? Or what is the best way of doing this with condition where value from variable

I'm using SQL Server 2008 (9.0 RTM)

This will be a stored procedure

Thanks in advance

Comment: check on dynamic query

Comment: i did use it and its good but i want to put condition like this Gnumber = '+@g

Comment: it gives me error invalid column name i want to display value from column

Comment: You can't use parameters for column or table names - if you want to "parametrize" this, you'll have to use dynamic SQL (with all its drawbacks and problems)

Comment: i think i didn't make my self clear look what i did i used the dynamic SQL and it works good but it display all the column that i gave it by a variable like this is my code

Comment: i will put my code in new question it doesn't allow me to put code in comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using dynamic sql but this is ***BAD*** practice.

Here's the answer to your problem but I most certainly wouldn't do this because it opens you up to sql injection attacks.

```
create procedure GetColumn
     @columnName varchar(50), 
     @g varchar(200)
as
   declare @str varchar(2000)
   set @str = 'select [' + @columnName + '] from dbo.tblBatchDetail where Gnumber = ' + @g

   exec ( @str ) 

GO
```

Comment: i did use dynamic query it works good but i want to add condition where from also variable like this Gnumber = '+@g

Comment: Could you not use [QUOTENAME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx) for the identifier and [sp_prepare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff848808.aspx), etc. for the scalar value to make this safer?